# replace eval to get value in form javascript

Tags: javascript, html

HTML script

```
<form method="POST" name="test">
<input type="hidden" name="test2" value="test3">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onClick="send()">
</form>
```

javascript

```
function send(){
   var form = document.test,
   a = eval("form.test2");
   alert(a.value); //test3
}
```

as you see the coding above, I use eval to get test2 value. but in some JS checker, eval is not allowed.. so how can I get that test2 value without eval function?

Comment: Just... remove the `eval`? `var a = form.test2;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this static example, modified code

```js
var send = function() {
  var test2 = document.test.test2.value; //static access without eval
  alert(test2);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="test">
  <input type="text" name="test2" value="test3">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return send()">
  <form>
```

Try this dynamic example, modified code

```js
var find = function(str) {
  var arr = str.split('.');
  var l = arr.length,
    i = 0;
  var el = window[arr[i++]]; //<-- we refer to js and html element right from here
  while (--l)
    el = el[arr[i++]];
  return el;
};

var send = function() {
  var prop = 'document.test.test2.value'; //<-- string name of the property to access
  var el = find(prop);
  alert(el);
  return false;
}

console.log(find('document')); //sample
console.log(find('alert')); //sample
```

```html
<form method="post" name="test">
  <input type="text" name="test2" value="test3">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="return send()">
  <form>
```

Comment: `form.test2` works just as well. Not sure what's supposed to be "dynamic" here. Why should the OP try that? Code without an explanation is rarely useful.

Comment: @FelixKling, what you call this statement `eval("form.test2");`?

Comment: @Arvind I haven't tried the second option yet. I thought the second option was so complicated, so I prepared to choose first option. thanks for sharing. I really appreciate what you've done.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `document.test.test2` will give you the form element with `name=test2` then you can use value on it.

```
<script>

function send(){

       var form = document.test;
       alert(document.test.test2.value);or form.test2.value which same as document.test.test2.value
      // alert(test2.value); //test3 
    }
</script>

<form method="POST" name="test">
<input type="hidden" name="test2" value="test3">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="send()">
</form>

**NOTE:** you should close your form tag first.
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? What did you change and why? Code without an explanation is rarely useful.

Comment: @suchit I just forgot to close form tag.. it was not a problem.. the problem was I didn't wanna use eval to get the value. if you used document.test.test2.value , it was just same as form.test2.value and it wouldn't work..